# double for loop with bash programming

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I'd like to do something like this with bash programming

```
for file_x in file1, file2, file3, etc...  
  for file_y in file1, file2, file3, etc...  
    if file_y != file_x
      do something
```

any tips how to go about it?

Comment: What kind of tips do you need? Your code is almost exactly correct; you just need to add `; do`s to the end of your `for` lines, a `; then` on the end of your `if`, and take out the `do` before `something`.

Comment: ...if you run `help for` and `help if` at your shell to see the syntax for each, and follow that syntax, there's literally nothing special about nesting your loops or conditionals; it's 100% precisely the same syntax you'd use if they weren't nested.

Comment: Is the issue that `file1, file2, etc` are the same? Stash them in an array: `files=( file1 file2 "file 3" ); for file_x in "${files[@]}"; do for file_y in "${files[@]}"; do ...`

Comment: ...and, of course, the conditional needs to use a `test` operator or equivalent: `if [ "$file_y" != "$file_x" ]; then`; your current code, `if file_y != file_x` tries to run `file_y` as a command, with `!=` as the first argument and `file_x` as the second argument.

Comment: ...but anyhow, all of this will be covered in any introduction to the language. StackOverflow is a place to go when you get stuck -- not a first resort to come to when you haven't tried any reference material yet. I'd suggest http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide

Comment: For a more advanced approach, instead of checking if the files have the same name, test if they are the same file (or link) using the `-ef` test operation.

Comment: Oh -- the commas also need to go. `for file_x in file1 file2 file3; do`

Comment: See http://shellcheck.net/ for more automated kibitzing, after you've first read some docs to have a non-guesswork-based idea of syntax. If you've got something you think should work per the docs and shellcheck, please do come back here.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

for file_x in "file1" "file2" "file3"
do  
  for file_y in "file1" "file2" "file3"
  do
    if cmp -q "$file_y" "$file_x"
    then
         echo "$file_y $file_x are equal"
    else
         echo "$file_y $file_x are not equal"
    fi
  done
done
```

Comment: Needs more quotes. Also, it looks to me like a comparison on the names is actually by user intent (to avoid operating the same directory entry against itself when present in both lists), rather than a content-based comparison.

Comment: ...but anyhow, if file1 is actually `"hello world.txt"`, then `cmp $file_y ...` won't treat it as a single argument, but will break it apart into `hello` and `world.txt`.

Comment: ...and if you _are_ going to use `cmp`, consider `cmp -q` -- that way it won't emit any results to stdout, and will exit as soon as it finds the first unequal byte, rather than continuing to compare two files it already knows don't match. (If file sizes differ, `cmp -q` can determine that the files don't match without needing to read contents at all, whereas `cmp` still needs to read through until it finds the end of one or the other).

Comment: ...and yes, as a C developer, I strongly prefer a style that's conservative of vertical space, maximizing the amount of code in view at a given time... so the preferences are, at least, consistent. In any event, as this has come down to a matter of bikeshedding, and I'm glad to retract my comments on that topic.

Comment: This is an honest attempt at an answer and so shouldn't be flagged as not an answer. If you don't like the answer, you should downvote it, not flag it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing an NxN comparison, it would make sense to only operate on the tail of the list in the inner loop.  Something like

```
#!/bin/bash

files=(foo bar baz quux)

for ((i=0; i<${#files[@]}-1; i++)); do
  for ((j=i+1; j<${#files[@]}; j++)); do
    maybe=""
    cmp -s "${files[$i]}" "${files[$j]}" || maybe=" not"
    echo "${files[$i]} and ${files[$j]} are$maybe equal"
  done
done
```